# Semidefinite relaxation for QCQP with nonconvex "homogeneous" constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, non-convex-optimization, qcqp, relaxations

Suppose we wish to solve the quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP) in $x \in \mathbb R^n$

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\text{minimize} & \frac{1}{2}x^\top Lx\\
\text{subject to} & Ax=b\\
& x^\top P_i x=0\ \forall x\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.
\end{array}$$

where $L \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, whereas matrices $P_i$ are not.

We can write a semidefinite relaxation of this problem as follows

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\min_{x\in\mathbb R^n, X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}}& \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(LX)\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & 
\begin{pmatrix} -b & A \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &x^\top\\x & X\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\end{pmatrix}
\\
& \mathrm{tr}(P_iX)=0\ \forall x\in\{1,\ldots,m\}\\
& \begin{pmatrix} 1 &x^\top\\x & X\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
\end{array}$$

Adding a constraint $X=xx^\top$ would make the above equivalent to the original QCQP.  The first constraint is obtained by writing $Ax=b$ as $$\begin{pmatrix}-b&A\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\x\end{pmatrix}=0$$ and post-multiplying both sides by $\begin{pmatrix}1&x^\top\end{pmatrix}$. I have several related questions:

1. Are there conditions under which the solution of the original QCQP is also optimal for the relaxed problem?  (i.e. relaxing may make the solution nonunique but not have a lower objective value)
2. Are there constraints I should add to the convex relaxation to make it tighter?
3. Are there conditions under which the optimal $X$ in the relaxed problem is rank-$1$?

---

Additional details in case they help:

- My $L$ has similar structure to a graph Laplacian
- Everything is convex in this problem except the (pesky) $P_i$ constraints, but these are "homogeneous" in the sense that they are purely degree-$2$ with zero on the right-hand side.
- The problem to which I'm applying this relaxation is a little complicated to explain in this post, but my experience experimentally is that, well, sometimes $X$ is rank-$1$ and sometimes it's low-rank but not rank-$1$.  I haven't figured out the pattern.

Comment: A rank-2 solution is less useful than you may expect, see [this paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~gf2293/CDC_Polynomial_2014.pdf).

Comment: Interesting!  (And a little depressing.)  So I guess it could be the case that our rank 2 answer is as good as a high-rank one.